# How to interpret the divergence of Fisher information expectation

Tags: probability, estimation, fisher-information

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to interpret the divergence of Fisher information expectation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/how-to-interpret-the-divergence-of-fisher-information-expectation)

Consider translated [Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) with probability density function:

$$
  f(x ; k, \lambda, \theta) = \frac{k}{\lambda} \left( \frac{x-\theta}{\lambda} \right)^{k-1} \exp\left( - \left(\frac{x-\theta}{\lambda} \right)^k \right) \chi_{x \ge \theta}(x)
$$

Consider $ \mathbb{E}\left( -\partial_\theta^2 \log f(x; k, \lambda, \theta) \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{k-1}{(x-\theta)^2  } \left(1 + \left( \frac{x-\theta}{\lambda}  \right)^k \right) \right)$. Notice that the expectation is only convergent for $k > 2$.

**Question**: What is the significance, or interpretation, of infinite matrix element of the Fisher information matrix ? Does it mean that the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ parameter is not asymptotically normal ?

Thank you for any light shed on the subject.

**Added**: I have received a satisfactory [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/how-to-interpret-the-divergence-of-fisher-information-expectation/15272#15272) to this question at stats.SE.