# Efficiency of chi-squared denoising

Tags: probability, estimation, point-estimation

Suppose my measurement $\theta+\epsilon$ is corrupted by IID additive noise $\epsilon$ distributed as chi-squared with (known) $d$ degrees of freedom, what is the efficiency of pooling multiple observations to infer $\theta$?

Using definition of Fisher information, I get the following expression for Fisher information of location parameter $\theta$, with singularity at $d=4$.

$$\frac{1}{2(d-4)}, d>4$$

[image]

Charles Zhang's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15272/511) suggests that divergence of Fisher information diverges implies that MLE converges faster than $O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

How fast is "fast" in this case? Is it polynomial in sample size for fixed $d$?

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/twitter-fisher-versus-covariance.nb)

Comment: What is the model of corruption?  $y_i=\theta+\epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i \sim \chi^2_d$ ?

Comment: @JimB ah, should've clarified that it's additive, yes

Comment: Isn't the MLE here converging to $\min(\theta)$ and this doesn't approache a normal distribution, or does it? How is convergence computed/expressed here?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus why would MLE converge to $\operatorname{min}(\theta)$? Likelihood graphs above for df=5 and df=4 look fairly similar

Comment: Maybe not exactly the same as $\min(\theta)$, but at least some skewness. You'd imagine that the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ would distribute somewhat around $\theta$, but the cases that we fit $\hat{\theta} > \theta$ might be low because observations need to be all larger than $\theta$.

Comment: I'm expecting that MLE estimates will center around $\theta+E[\chi^2_d]$

Comment: So how is convergence expressed? Using the variance of the estimation error?

Comment: If we use a method of moments estimator, which are unbiased, then we have an estimator that will center around $\theta$. (e.g. the mean of the observations minus a correction $\bar{X}-d$). I would expect the MLE to be close to this, except that sometimes it is cut-off due to the constraint that we need $\hat{\theta} \leq \min{X}$.

Comment: Yes, curious about variance of the MLE estimator of $\theta$ for $\chi^2_d+\theta$. As $d$ approaches 4 from above, Fisher Information of $\theta$ approaches 0. The other [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/how-to-interpret-the-divergence-of-fisher-information-expectation/15272#15272) suggests that in this setting, MLE converges slower than $O(1/\sqrt{n})$, how much slower?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to assess effect of sample size (which I'm assuming is what you mean by "pooling multiple observations") is to use simulations to estimate the bias and variance of the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

Here is the log likelihood for various values of $\theta$, $d$, and $n$ (sample size) with the observations being $y_1,\ldots,y_n$:

$$\log L=\text{constant} + (d-2) \sum _{i=1}^n \log (y_i-\theta )+n\theta $$

I know you have access to *Mathematica* so here is such code to examine a few sample sizes with $d=4$ and $\theta=1$:

```
d = 4;
dist = TransformedDistribution[θ + ϵ, ϵ \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[d]];
nsim = 100;
n = {10, 50, 100, 500, 1000};
mean = ConstantArray[0, Length[n]];
var = ConstantArray[0, Length[n]];
mle = ConstantArray[0, nsim];
Do[
 Do[y = RandomVariate[dist /. θ -> 1, n[[k]]];
  logL = (d - 2) Sum[Log[y[[i]] - θ], {i, 1, n[[k]]}] + 
    n[[k]]  θ;
  mle[[j]] = θ /. 
    FindMaximum[{logL, θ <= Min[y]}, θ][[2]],
  {j, 1, nsim}];
 mean[[k]] = Mean[mle];
 var[[k]] = Variance[mle],
 {k, 1, Length[n]}]

data = Transpose[{n, mean, var}];
lmf = LinearModelFit[Log[data[[All, {1, 3}]]], logn, logn];
lmf["BestFitParameters"]
(* {1.44996, -1.19787} *)

Show[ListLogLogPlot[data[[All, {1, 3}]],
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Sample size", "Variance"}],
  LogLogPlot[Exp[lmf[Log[nn]]], {nn, 10, 1000}]]
```

[image: Plot of sample size vs variance]

Note that when $d=1$ and $d=2$, the maximum likelihood estimator is the minimum of the observed values (as suggested by @SextusEmpiricus).

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. 1. I tried to run your code but ran out of patience after waiting 10 seconds for it to generate results 2. The interesting graph to me would be the graph comparing efficiency in practice against sqrt(n) predicted by classical theory.